# How was Dorsey able to measure speed of light with 3 significant digits?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, measurements, history, experimental-technique

How was Dorsey able to measure [speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) with 3 significant digits in the year of 1907?

Comment: How does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Electromagnetic_constants fail to answer the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They just had to measure the capacitance of a capacitor!

If you can build a precise dimensioned capacitor you can work out it's capacitance with an equation including the [vacuum permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity)  ($ε_0$).  It's easy to build the dimensions of the metal plates in a capacitor to high accuracy, and you can measure current accurately so by measuring the capacitance you get an experimental value for this constant.

Then you get a value of $c$ from  $c^2 = 1/(ε_0μ_0)$
$μ_0$ is fixed by definition of the electrical units you are using.